# Div contenteditable and pressing "enter" on FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have got a div with contenteditable that should trigger a < br /> insert on "enter".
Everything works fine in IE but Firefox drives me crazy.

```
this.e.keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    var execute = editor.insertHTML(\'<br />\')';
    eval(execute);
    return false;
  } 
});
```

Firefox ignores < br /> at the end of the div and I guess at the beginning too. Means, if I press "enter" at the middle of a sentence, it works as it should. Trying the same at the end of a sentence (the very last one) it fails.

Any ideas? The same problem we have at the **stackoverflow editor preview** :-)

Press "enter" at the end > fail ... press "enter" a single letter earlier > newline

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable

Comment: insertHTML(\'<br />&nbsp\')'; fixes it temporary but cause the ugly nbsp...

Comment: Check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

Add this function instead

```
this.e.keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.charCode == 13) {
        var execute = editor.insertHTML(\'<br />\')';
        eval(execute);
        return false;
    } 
});
```

FF reads charCode instead of keyCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting `<br /><span></span>`.  This moves the cursor to the next line but doesn't properly resize the container so it isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[contentEditable - Firefox <br /> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705580/contenteditable-firefox-br-tag) check here, it might  give an idea :)