# How to force <br> line break in Firefox ContentEditable

Tags: html, firefox, wysiwyg

I have a JavaScript WYSIWYG editor (not unlike CKEditor) running on a site.

It has a setting that makes IE create `<br>` line breaks when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the editor.

That works great, but unfortunately, Firefox (I've tested with 5 and 7) will still generate `<p>` elements, and generate `<br>` s only if you use <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd>.

Is there a way to make Firefox always generate `<br>` elements in a contentEditable?

Comment: Weirdly enough, there's a SO question complaining about the exact opposite: [contentEditable - Firefox <br /> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5705580) But in FF5 and FF7, I am positive I am seeing `<p>` tags being used

Comment: Is a JavaScript solution acceptable?

Comment: In my Firefox (7.0.1 on Win7), when I press ENTER inside [this DIV](http://jsfiddle.net/FhEf6/show/), a `<br _moz_dirty="">` element is inserted.

Comment: My experience in other browsers: the latest Chrome inserts `<div>` elements, and IE9 and Opera insert `<p>` elements. Since the behavior is not consistent across browsers, I recommend you to just `e.preventDefault()` inside the `keypress` handler if ENTER is pressed, and then manually insert `<br>` or `\n`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From looking at the standards, it looks like this action is the way it is supposed to be handled. Blocks are broken when no modifier is set on an enter key, and `<br>`'s are used when shift is pressed. [[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/editing.html#contenteditable)].

That said, that does not solve your problem, so let's work on that. This line should do

```
document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn', false, true);
```

Set's it so that when you just hit return, it only puts in a `<br>` tag. This is [only supported by FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla), so it shouldn't affect anything on IE. Don't know about other browsers though.

**Note:** If the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time, without typing anything, it creates a new paragraph tag no matter what. To prevent this, you can catch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> using the `keypress` event and stop it, or you could insert in a `&nbsp;` before you continue with the event (what I'd recommend).

The tough part for you with this note is checking on the state of the element on `keypress`. The lazy solution (and the one I would recommend unless it's important to not do this) is to just insert it before every <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If you want to do it the other way, I would check the `.innerHTML` for the element and see if the last few characters (without trimming the content) are `<br/>` (so maybe a regex match on `/\<br\s?\/?\>$/`).

Comment: Very interesting - I will be testing this soon.

Comment: This fixes my immediate problem most directly, so awarding the bounty to you. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to see a 7 year old answer, which actually solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Consider this:

HTML:

```
<div contentEditable id="input"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
    border: 3px solid #07c;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$( input ).keypress( function ( e ) {
    var sel, node, offset, text, textBefore, textAfter, range;

    sel = window.getSelection();

    // the node that contains the caret
    node = sel.anchorNode;

    // if ENTER was pressed while the caret was inside the input field
    if ( node.parentNode === input && e.keyCode === 13 ) {

        // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
        e.preventDefault();

        // the caret position inside the node
        offset = sel.anchorOffset;        

        // insert a '\n' character at that position
        text = node.textContent;
        textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
        textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
        node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

        // position the caret after that new-line character
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
        range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );

        // update the selection
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange( range );
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FhEf6/3/

I use `'\n'` characters instead of BR elements (the DIV has `white-space:pre` set). As a result, no BR, or P elements are added to the DIV when ENTER is pressed. There is only one TextNode inside the DIV at all times and all new-lines are represented by `'\n'` characters.

Comment: Looks interesting - I will test this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

// not exactly what you asked but this function may be interesting when you want to force
// the other browsers opera,chrome,internet explorer to insert a regular BR on enter.
// could be better written but works so far

```
enterBR = function(e)
{   
    var iframeElement=parent.window.$("wysiwyg"+n);
    e = e || iframeElement.contentWindow.event;                 // eventhandler inside iframe (!)
    var keyCode= e.keyCode? e.keyCode: e.which;                 // req. for IE below v8

if (keyCode==13)                                // if enter key gets pressed
{ 
     if(IE)      // internet explorer
     { e.preventDefault?e.preventDefault():e.returnValue=false; // block default handling ( i tell yo!)
       iframeElement.contentDocument.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<br/>");  // insert a br tag
     }

     if(OP||CR)  // opera and chrome
     { 
      iframeElement.contentWindow.document.execCommand('formatBlock',false,'p');
     } // creates a paragraph around a br tag <p><br/></p> replace with regExp

    //here the regExp to replace the unneeded paragraph tags and a detection if you have whatever xhtml compatible <br/>'s or not.
    HTML=iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    HTML=HTML.replace(/<p><br([\/]?)><\/p>/gi,'<br/>');
    HTML=HTML.replace(/<br(.*?|\s*[^\/]+[^>]?)([\/]?)>/mgi,"<br$1/>\n"); 

}
  return false;
}

// finaly add an eventlistener. remember this is used inside an iframe so dont forget to advise the script to work from one dom layer above (parent.window)
// but i think it can be easily rewritten for contenteditable div or something...
addEventListener(parent.window.$("mywysiwygeditor").contentDocument,'keypress',enterBR);
```

// hf

Answer (score 0):

My solution works perfectly in Firefox, although it came around quite unexpectedly! I've also tested it in Edge and Chrome. It's based on the answer of @Ktash, replacing the nbsp with three disappearing nodes: an empty span (with a class), a `<br>` in the middle and a span containing `&nbsp;`.

JS:

```
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn', false, true);

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');
Array.from(elements).forEach( (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if (isFirefox) {
                document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span class="nbsp-break"></span><br><span>&nbsp;</span>');
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (!isChrome) {
                document.execCommand('insertText', true, '\r\n');
                document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<br>");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

    if (isFirefox) {
        el.addEventListener('input',function(e) {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nbsp-break');
            Array.from(elements).forEach( (el) => {
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el.nextSibling.nextSibling);
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.nbsp-break + br + span {
    font-size: 0;
}
```