# Insert just opening HTML tags after an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to insert a couple of opening DIV tags after the H1 element on a page, without inserting the corresponding closing tags (since the closing tags are contained in an included footer file which I don't have access to).

i.e.
Existing code:

```
<body>
<h1>Heading One</h1>
... page content...
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

New code:

```
<body>    
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<div id="foo">  
<div id="baa">  
... page content...
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

DOM methods insert the div as a complete (closed) element, 'createTextNode' inserts escaped characters and 'innerHTML' needs an element to insert into. Have even tried to insert a script element with document.write without any luck.

Any ideas (jQuery would be fine)?

**Update**
The following worked:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('</h1>','</h1><div id="foo"><div id="baa">')
```

As pointed out by *Asad* the solution (which now seems obvious of course) is to use string methods on the HTML rather than DOM methods.

Comment: @f00bar Won't work -- the browser will automatically close any open tags. This is how the DOM is supposed to work. OP is confusing the DOM with HTML source.

Comment: I would try the .html() method with no conviction to insert missing tags

Comment: Try .after() or .append()/.prepend()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paste </p> closing tag without spawning an opening p tag in contenteditable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431323/paste-p-closing-tag-without-spawning-an-opening-p-tag-in-contenteditable)

Comment: @banzsh .after() inserts the closing tags and append() inserts inside the h1 ellement rather than following it

Comment: @f00bar h1.html() will insert within the h1 rather than after it

Comment: @pelms thx I already knew that ... I just did not read the whole post and rushed to the comment area `:p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with DOM manipulation, use DOM manipulation methods. If you're dealing with HTML manipulation, use string manipulation methods.

```
h1.parentElement.innerHTML = h1.parentElement.innerHTML.replace("<h1>Heading One</h1>","<h1>Heading One</h1><div><div>");
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. Getting "Reference error - h1 not defined" but can see what you're getting at. 'document.body.innerHTML' works.

Comment: @pelms That is because you need to assign the `h1` node to this variable first, I didn't include that part. Something like: `var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];`

Comment: Got it. I was being too literal.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will answer your question, it is all about valid XML formation.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: I see that the DOM methods have to create valid HTML but what I was looking for was a workaround to insert a fragment of HTML without regard to its validity at that point (the final page would be valid HTML as the closing tags are contained in the footer).

Answer (score 0):

Forget DOM methods, insert it as a string using .replace().

Comment: What string would you use replace() on?

Comment: You're replace the innerHTML of an element: document.body = document.body.replace('</h1>','</h1><div>')

Comment: The problem with this approach, as with Asad's is that the close `</div>` tags will have been discarded by the parser, so the end position of the div elements will be unknown.

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('</h1>','</h1><div id="foo"><div id="baa">') worked! Many thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus. Asad just beat you to it.

Comment: I get the down-vote, he gets the correct answer for basically saying the same thing. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong. The browser parses the DOM as it sees it, and automatically closes any tags that ought to be closed.  It's impossible to use JavaScript to insert only the opening tag.

You say "the closing tags are contained in an included footer file which I don't have access to." Closed tags that haven't been opened are ignored, so as far as the DOM parser is concerned, those closing tags don't exist.

Your solution is either:

1. Put the opening tags in a header, or somewhere else on the server-side, or
2. Use JavaScript to grab ALL the following DOM elements, including the footer, and [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) them all in the desired divs.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of practice seems a bit unorthodox, but perhaps something like this would help.

Existing HTML

```
<h1 id="testH1">Test H1</h1>
<div id="existingDiv">
    <div id="existingDivContent">Existing Div Content</div>
</div>
```

New HTML

```
<h1 id="testH1">Test H1</h1>
<div id="newDiv">
    <div id="existingDiv">
        <div id="existingDivContent">Existing Div Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

The javascript is fairly rudimentary, but I think the concept can be applied to safely and properly achieve your goal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //-- parent node you wish to copy
    var existingDiv = $('#existingDiv');

    //-- new parent div node
    var newDiv = $('<div id="newDiv">');

    //-- where we want to insert the new parent node
    var testH1 = $('#testH1');

    //-- stuff our previous parent node into our new parent node
    newDiv.html(existingDiv);

    //-- insert into the DOM
    testH1.after(newDiv);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qzvN/

Comment: Thanks @Don but what I'm after is to just insert the opening div tags rather than wrap the content in a new div (I've expanded my question to make this more clear)