# Dealing with line Breaks on contentEditable DIV

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, sanitization

I have a problem with `contenteditable` line breaks on SAFARI/CHROME. When I press "return" on a contentEditable `<div>`, instead of creating a `<br>` (like Firefox), they create a new `<div>`:

```
<div>Something</div>
<div>Something</div>
```

That looks like (on the contentEditable DIV):

```
Something
Something
```

But after sanitization (removing `<div>`), I get this:

```
SomethingSomething
```

In Firefox, the `contenteditable` is:

```
Something
<br>
Something
```

And that after sanitization looks the same:

```
Something
Something
```

Is there any solution to "normalize" this across browsers?

I've found this code on [Make a <br> instead of <div></div> by pressing Enter on a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable)

```
$(function(){

  $("#editable")

  // make sure br is always the lastChild of contenteditable
  .live("keyup mouseup", function(){
    if (!this.lastChild || this.lastChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "br") {
      this.appendChild(document.createChild("br"));
     }
  })

  // use br instead of div div
  .live("keypress", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
      if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection(),
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
          br = document.createElement("br");
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(br);
        range.setStartAfter(br);
        range.setEndAfter(br);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This works, but **(in SAFARI and CHROME)** I have to press two times the "return" key to get a new line...

Any idea?

**Edit**: With the code I found ( at the bottom of this question) is working fine except the function that "makes sure a `<br>` element is always the lastChild... Any idea on how to fix this?

**Edit 2:** I'm getting this error on the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'createChild'`

**Edit 3:** Ok, I changed the `document.createChild("br");` to `document.createElement("br");` and I think I got it working in FF/Safari/Chrome... All return `<br>` for new lines...

**The problem is now that when I'm inside an Ordered or Unordered List, I need to get a new line without `<br>`...**

**Edit 4:** If anyone interested in the solution of the last edit: [Avoid createElement function if it's inside a <LI> element (contentEditable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024594/avoid-createelement-function-if-its-inside-a-li-element-contenteditable)

Comment: what does your sanitization method look like?

Comment: @mdmullinax It just removes all the <div>... I'm using https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js The problem is that Safari/Chrome, when I press return, they just create a new DIV instead of making a <BR> like Firefox

Comment: Maybe you can use $("div:empty").replaceWith("<br/>");

Comment: Did you find anything useful for the bug of the two return keys? I have ran accross the same problem, the only thing I seem to be able to do is a hack (add an empty text and select it so if you continue to write it will automatically disappear), I'll be posting in on that thread just in case.
It's not perfect but it works.

Comment: Firefox now has a hybrid approach: it wraps the <br>s inside <div>s. This makes it behave similarly to Chrome, I guess because react removes the <div>s entirely, including the <br>s.

Answer (score 32):

This technique appears to avoid the Chrome bug that does show BRs the first time (with the code you mentionned you need to push two times the Enter key).

It's not a perfect hack but it works: it adds a whitespace after your BR so it show properly.
However, you will see that adding only a whitespace " " will NOT change anything, it works with other letters. The browser will not show it, probably because it is like a blank space inside an html page, it simply does not mean anything. To get rid of that bug I created a div with jQuery that includes a `&nbsp;` tag, and I take the `text()` property to put it in the textnode otherwise it doesn't work.

```
$editables = $('[contenteditable=true]');

$editables.filter("p,span").on('keypress',function(e){
 if(e.keyCode==13){ //enter && shift

  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
  if (window.getSelection) {
      var selection = window.getSelection(),
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
          br = document.createElement("br"),
          textNode = document.createTextNode("\u00a0"); //Passing " " directly will not end up being shown correctly
      range.deleteContents();//required or not?
      range.insertNode(br);
      range.collapse(false);
      range.insertNode(textNode);
      range.selectNodeContents(textNode);

      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      return false;
  }

   }
});
```

Comment: Add range.deleteContents(); before selection.removeAllRanges();to get rid of those pesky &nbsp; while keeping it all work ^^

Comment: Adding document.execCommand('delete') just before "return false" does the trick and does not show selected whitespace selection.

Answer (score 21):

You can simply use following command
`document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'<br>');`

This command will prevent default behavior and add a tag you wish.
That's all, 1 line of code

And even easier approach.

CSS ONLY.

To you contenteditable element apply `display:inline-block` rule
and this will add **br**s only

Comment: This css approach is awesome! Cheers @Karb

Comment: None of these two solutions work for me. Tried with "keypress", "keydown" and "keyup", and with these two solutions at a time. But Firefox is still creating DIVS :/

Comment: Note that you will never get the same behavior from the browsers if you only slap `contenteditable=true` because the end user visible behavior has not been specified and every browser vendor has different ideas. You have to use more or less full JS implementation to get browsers emit the output you want. One common option is to use TinyMCE which is now licensed with MIT license so using it (with open source plugins) is free for all.

Answer (score 16):

Listening to keystrokes seems like a lot of work. Would something as simple as this be feasible:

```
var html = $('.content').html().replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,'');
```

JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WXexS/).

Also, it looks like [sanitize.js](https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js) allows a custom configuration. Have you tried adding `div` as an allowed element?

Allowing HTML/CSS is dangerous, so ensure you are being extra cautious.

**EDIT:** Removed server side comments. Sanitising occurs at time of usage- if the client wants to bypass this locally it can be done so at their own risk. Thanks [Vincent McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16299/vincent-mcnabb) for pointing this out.

Comment: It looks like the sanitisation is done for display purposes, not security purposes, in which case it is perfectly reasonable to do it on the client. They can bypass it if they want, and all it would do is make things look ugly for them.

Comment: I believe sanitisation is done for security purposes at the time of usage (e.g, stripping unsafe tokens for HTML output). You make an excellent point that if the client wants to bypass this locally it can be done so at their own risk.

Comment: Are you trying to parse Html with Regex? before you do that, read advice here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3):

Webkits won’t render a single `br` if it’s the last (non-empty) child of a container. For Safari, the native keystroke to insert a line break is Ctrl + Return. If you look closely, you notice that Safari actually inserts two `br`s while only rendering one; however, it will insert a single `br` if there is some trailing text, or will get rid of double `br`s once you enter some (if there were doubles).

Apparently, it seems a solution for Webkits is to insert double `br`s as they themselves do, and let them handle the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "br");
```

The complete reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the css `white-space` property. Setting the style to `white-space: pre-wrap` allows you to get rid of all that javascript, because it changes the behavior of whitespace to display instead of collapse.

And see this answer: [HTML - Newline char in DIV content editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038070/html-newline-char-in-div-content-editable)

Comment: This issue still happens no matter what white-space is set to, this has to do with contentEditable

Answer (score 0):

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/BmTNP/5/)

Or this post

[How to parse editable DIV's text with browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821102/how-to-parse-editable-divs-text-with-browser-compatibility/12832377#12832377)

Answer (score 0):

The use case generally occurs when you are prefilling the data in a content editable div & resending it to the server.

Eg. - Like editing a post on a social media website, to mitigate this I have created new div for each new line.

```
let conD =data.postDescription.split('\n');
let conH = "";
conD.forEach((d)=>{
        conH +=`<div>${d}</div>`;
       });
$("#contentbox").html(conH);
```