# Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` element, and whenever I type some stuff and hit `ENTER` it creates a new `<div>` and places the new line text in there. I don't like this one little bit.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening or at least just replace it with a `<br>`?

Here is demo **http://jsfiddle.net/jDvau/**

Note: **This is not an issue in firefox.**

Comment: firefox adds <br>, chrome - not, but after fixing your styles, extra divs do not break left padding. Question is why you dont like it? Think it is br... http://jsfiddle.net/jDvau/1/ Also you can use DOMSubtreeModified event on catch these divs and remove them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024594/avoid-createelement-function-if-its-inside-a-li-element-contenteditable this could help you, good luck!

Comment: have also a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable

Comment: Possible duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable

Comment: To me Blake Plumb's solution is the simplest and from far the best down here.

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: @svassr that's not the point, it's not you or I that will be using it, It's a client that may not even know what shift is.

Comment: Indeed it changes everything. That said it's a common behaviour and small help message would'nt arm. "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: need add ```e.preventDefault()``` before ```return false```

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
    // trap the return key being pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the next line)
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br/>');
        // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uff3M/)**

Comment: But I find a little difference here. Put your cursor just on the blank line(on the top of "Type some stuff"), and press enter. The cursor is now just before the "Type", not on the new blank line.

Comment: @Andrew yes that is correct, It would be good if you can fix this Ram

Comment: I am sorry I can't find an easy fix for this at the moment & I am a little busy with work & all, I will try my best to find a workaround for this issue soon

Comment: This doesn't work in IE11 as it does not support insertHTML. See answer below!

Comment: In chrome if you try this within a blockquote, it automatically creates a new blockquote as well, not the desired behavior.

Comment: If you put your cursor between characters eg. 'Ty[cursor]pe some stuff' and hit enter, you get 1 line too many.

Comment: Answer is not acceptable. Solution would be to have only one <br />

Comment: this return both <br> and <div>

Comment: if there is multiple contentEditable then it will insert extra br. If there is four contentEditable then four break will occur

Comment: answers half the question without trying to answer the first part, which is to prevent this from happening

Comment: another prob here is that it takes no account of modifiers... when using `keydown` you want to do sthg like  `if ... && ! e.ctrlKey && ! e.shiftKey && ! e.altKey` as appropriate...

Comment: The `insertHTML` command will indeed produce some weird results when you have nested `contenteditable` elements. Andrew's answer, where you replace the current selection with a new document fragment, is better for this.

Comment: I want to do this whiling pasting text, is it possible?

Comment: I find it will not insert `<br>` when the cursor is before a `<br>`. Chrome 80. Weird.

Comment: I have added a modern solution (check below), which actually works as expected.

Comment: A solution with pure javascript is preferred.

Comment: `.execCommand()` is now considered obsolete by MDN... See [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Answer (score 70):

Add style `display:inline-block;` to `contenteditable`, it will not generate `div`, `p` and `span` automatically in Chrome.

Comment: This is a great solution. `*[contenteditable="true"]{display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Love it, simple but effective

Comment: In IE11 this will make an extra ``<p></p>``  :(

Comment: This solved a line break problem I was trying to fix for the last six months!  Thank you @le-tung-anh

Comment: ericjbasti's CSS snippet *is not a great solution* performance-wise. Wildcard selectors are costly. Make sure to specify it for elements that actually will use it.

Comment: Does not work anymore with Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84

Comment: With the answer of @airi, I discovered that the contenteditable should be a <div>. It cannot be a <span> or a <body> for this idea to work

Comment: Glad this works, but it's dumb that this works. The difference between `inline-block` and `block` is supposed to be in the flow [**outside the element**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/673991). This solution reveals a distinction Chrome makes inside the element. Chrome should behave the same for `display:block`.

Comment: This doesn't work when the element is a grid child. The inline-block will not do anything, and pressing Enter still inserts <div>s.

Comment: great! simple enough, now it inserts <br> instead of <div>

Comment: @Bob Stein - Wanted to add to this thread here - adding a wrapper div around the contenteditable div with inline-block display allows this to work inside a grid child!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670758/contenteditable-inside-a-css-grid-element-seems-to-be-a-bug-in-google-chrome

Comment: It seems to work again in Chrome 119. Phew!

Comment: does not work for me in chrome 121

Comment: @raquelhortab What the heck? MaxPekarsky had Chrome version 119 and it worked for him. You have version 121 and it doesn't work for you. I have Chrome version 122 and it works for me. Maybe it's not the version but rather the OS? I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 55):

You can do this with just a CSS change:

```
div{
    background: skyblue;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

pre{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/HW43Q/

Comment: There was a problem when I used inline-block, execute execCommand("insertHTML", xxx) to insert anything, a "<br>" will added at the end of inserted element, tested in Chrome33.

Comment: Nice find. Sadly this won't work on position: absolute elements or elements that are direct children of a parent with display: flex. You can hack it to work though keeping that in mind. Just make sure it's not a direct child of flex elements. If you need it position: absolute just give it a extra parent with that.

Comment: @ReinoutvanKempen Started using flex 3 months ago already. I guess this hack won't work

Comment: this is a really really greatest solution, it is extreme clean and clear, nothing will be insert, even include br. and especially this solution without js.

Comment: Wow... this solves Chrome, but makes Firefox begin adding divs on enter, which it doesn't by default.

Comment: This also doesn't work when the element is a grid child. The inline-block will not do anything, and pressing Enter still inserts <div>s.

Answer (score 48):

This works in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge)

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    document.execCommand('insertLineBreak')
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="element" contenteditable="true">Sample text</div>
<p class="element" contenteditable="true">Sample text</p>
```

There is one inconvenience. After you finish editing, the elements might contain an ending `<br>` inside. But you could add code to trim that down if you need to.

Check this answer to remove the trailing `<br>` https://stackoverflow.com/a/61237737/670839

Comment: What the heck?  How can the only solution that actually worked for me be this far down the page?  Thanks so much.

Comment: You just made my day, this took hours to figure out - thanks!

Comment: execCommand is depricated! This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards.

Comment: This works right now for all major browsers and will likely continue to work as no one ever removes stuff from the web.

Comment: This works great for browsers not supporting `contentEditable="plaintext-only"`, and can be used by almost all browsers.

Comment: execCommand is now deprecated and should not be used

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').keypress(function(event) {

    if (event.which != 13)
        return true;

    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    //add a new line
    var newEle = document.createTextNode('\n');
    docFragment.appendChild(newEle);

    //add the br, or p, or something else
    newEle = document.createElement('br');
    docFragment.appendChild(newEle);

    //make the br replace selection
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(docFragment);

    //create a new range
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartAfter(newEle);
    range.collapse(true);

    //make the cursor there
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/jDvau/3/

Comment: Good, works :) I'll await more attention before I decide, thanks.

Comment: doesn't work properly on firefox. it adds one extra line.

Comment: This makes it so that the `input` doesn't get triggered when you press enter. A simple solution: add sth like `$(this).trigger('input')`

Comment: The `insertHTML` solution does some weird things when there are nested `contenteditable` elements, your solution circumvents that but there are some more issues, I added it as a new possible solution.

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome. First time when you press enter at the end of the string, it adds a space. The second time it works though.

Comment: I am using a contenteditable with a child div inside and want to enter new line in that div. The code works well but not if I enter at the end of the line. At the end of the line, I have to enter twice for a new line.

Answer (score 25):

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
```

It overrides the default behavior to have paragraph instead.

On chrome the default behavior on enter is:

```
<div>
    <br>
</div>
```

With that command it is gonna be

```
<p>
    <br>
</p>
```

Now that it's more linear across it's easy to have only `<br>` would you need to.

Comment: When you press enter, instead of having div and br you'll have p and br accross browser. Try it.

Comment: Thanks! Explanations are always helpful

Comment: @jpaugh np, I edited my answer further so it explains better.

Comment: this doesn't work on firefox (I tested in chrome and firefox only)

Comment: FireFox has been fixed to now respect the defaultParagraphSeparator.

IMHO this make this answer the best as it make all browsers now consistent and inline with the spec. If you then don't want a P tag to have a margin 'spacing' from the previous text block in content editable then you can use css to modify that.

Comment: I does execute twice for the first time.

Comment: This was the best fix after hours of search. IE11 and modern browsers work with this solution.

Comment: This is nice but I really wish you could change it to just `br` and not have the extra `p` tag at all.

Answer (score 21):

On the W3C Editor's Draft there are some information about adding states into [ContentEditable](https://w3c.github.io/contentEditable/#contenteditable-states), and to prevent the browser for adding new element when pressing enter you can use `plaintext-only`.

```html
<div contentEditable="plaintext-only"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for me. It does not add div or br.

Comment: this is what I needed!

Comment: It is still in very early stage. only 57% browser support as of Dec 2021

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm. But Firefox and IE still not supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable . I can check browser to load hacked work around in FF and IE.

Comment: This is the right answer for evergreen browsers in 2022

Answer (score 13):

Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>enter</kbd> to just put a single `<br>` tag in or wrap your text in `<p>` tags.

Comment: **+1** Thanks, this is very handy to know, but if you have a client that's writing a book, that'll be a pain in the ***

Comment: This doesn't help if you're pasting content

Answer (score 6):

The way that `contenteditable` behaves when you press <kbd>enter</kbd> depends on browsers, the `<div>` happens on webkit (chrome, safari) and IE.

I struggled with this few month ago and I corrected it this way :

```
//I recommand you trigger this in case of focus on your contenteditable
if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("msie") > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("webkit") > 0 ) {
    //Add <br> to the end of the field for chrome and safari to allow further insertion
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("webkit") > 0)
    {
        if ( !this.lastChild || this.lastChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "br" ) {
            $(this).html( $(this).html()+'<br />' );
        }
    }

    $(this).keypress( function(e) {
        if( ( e.keyCode || e.witch ) == 13 ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("msie") > 0 ) {
                insertHtml('<br />');
            }
            else {
              var selection = window.getSelection(),
              range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
              br = document.createElement('br');

              range.deleteContents();
              range.insertNode(br);
              range.setStartAfter(br);
              range.setEndAfter(br);
              range.collapse(false);

              selection.removeAllRanges();
              selection.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope it will help, and sorry for my english if it's not as clear as needed.

**EDIT** : Correction of removed jQuery function `jQuery.browser`

Comment: Just to let you know, `jQuery.browser` is no longer part of jQuery.

Comment: You've right, I should mention this and use something like `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("msie") > 0` and `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("webkit") > 0`

Comment: `if( ( e.keyCode || e.witch ) == 13 ) { ... }` needs to be `if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

You can have separate `<p>` tags for each line rather than using `<br>` tags and gain greater browser compatibility out of the box.

To do this, put a `<p>` tag with some default text inside of the contenteditable div.

For example, instead of:

```
<div contenteditable></div>
```

Use:

```
<div contenteditable>
   <p>Replace this text with something awesome!</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwwah0s6/)

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, and the second works the same in each.

The first, however, creates divs in Chrome, creates line breaks in Firefox, and in Edge creates divs *and* the cursor is put back at the beginning of the current div instead of moving into the next one.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

Comment: this is actually not a bad solution

Answer (score 5):

The `inserHTML` command solution does some weird things when you have nested `contenteditable` elements.

I took some ideas from multiple answers here, and this seems to suit my needs for now:

```
element.addEventListener('keydown', function onKeyDown(e) {

    // Only listen for plain returns, without any modifier keys
    if (e.which != 13 || e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        return;
    }

    let doc_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Create a new break element
    let new_ele = document.createElement('br');
    doc_fragment.appendChild(new_ele);

    // Get the current selection, and make sure the content is removed (if any)
    let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();

    // See if the selection container has any next siblings
    // If not: add another break, otherwise the cursor won't move
    if (!hasNextSibling(range.endContainer)) {
        let extra_break = document.createElement('br');
        doc_fragment.appendChild(extra_break);
    }

    range.insertNode(doc_fragment);

    //create a new range
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartAfter(new_ele);
    range.collapse(true);

    //make the caret there
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});

// See if the given node has a next sibling.
// Either any element or a non-empty node
function hasNextSibling(node) {

    if (node.nextElementSibling) {
        return true;
    }

    while (node.nextSibling) {
        node = node.nextSibling;

        if (node.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Man. Thank you for the code, it saved me!.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use Mousetrap for handlling hotkeys: https://craig.is/killing/mice

Then, I just intercept the enter event, executing a command **insertLineBreak**:

```
Mousetrap.bindGlobal('enter', (e)=>{
  window.document.execCommand('insertLineBreak', false, null);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

> All commands: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

It works using Chrome 75 and the following editable element:

```
<pre contenteditable="true"></pre>
```

It's also possible to use **insertHTML**:

```
window.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "\n");
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything on my end…

Answer (score 4):

I'd use styling (Css) to fix the issue.

```
div[contenteditable=true] > div {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Firefox indeed adds a the block element break 
, whereas Chrome wraps each section in a  tag. You css gives divs a padding of *10px* along with the background color.

```
div{
  background: skyblue;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can replicate the same desired effect in jQuery:

```
var style = $('<style>p[contenteditable=true] > div { padding: 0;}</style>');
$('html > head').append(style);
```

Here's a fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R4Jdz/7/

Comment: This may help some people but I was more concerned about the unessasary markup, as I would be taking the final HTML of the `contenteditable` and using it elsewhere

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your paragraphs with `<p>` tag for example it would apper on new line instead of div
Example:
`<div contenteditable="true"><p>Line</p></div>` 
After inserting new string:
`<div contenteditable="true"><p>Line</p><p>New Line</p></div>`

Answer (score 2):

add a prevent default to the div

```
document.body.div.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if ( e.keycode == 13 ){
        e.preventDefault();
            //add a <br>
        div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        div.innerHTML += "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @connorspiracist sorry its `document.body.div` (you probably will need to put in some other code to point to correct `div` its just the general idea)

Answer (score 2):

Try using ckeditor. It also provide formatting like this one in SOF.

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

First we need to capture every key user enter to see if enter is pressed then we prevent the `<div>` creation and we create our own `<br>` tag.

There's one problem, when we create it our cursor stay at the same position so we use [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to place our cursor at the end.

Don't forget to add a `<br>` tag at the end of your text because if you don't the first enter won't do a new line.

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode,
        el  = $(this)[0];
    // If Enter    
    if (key === 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the <div /> creation.
        $(this).append('<br>'); // Add the <br at the end

        // Place selection at the end 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            range.collapse(false);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.collapse(false);
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDvau/9/)**

Answer (score 2):

This is browser directed HTML5 editor. You can wrap your text with `<p>...</p>`, then whenever you press ENTER you get `<p></p>`. Also, the editor works this way that whenever you press SHIFT+ENTER it inserts `<br />`.

```
<div contenteditable="true"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor veniam asperiores laudantium repudiandae doloremque sed perferendis obcaecati delectus autem perspiciatis aut excepturi et nesciunt error ad incidunt impedit quia dolores rerum animi provident dolore corporis libero sunt enim. Ad magnam omnis quidem qui voluptas ut minima similique obcaecati doloremque atque!
<br /><br />
Type some stuff, hit ENTER a few times, then press the button.
</p>
</div>
```

Check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQztJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) {
   var range = document.getSelection();
   range.pasteHTML(range.htmlText + '<br><br>');
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1)                           {
   var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); //get caret
   var nnode = document.createElement('br');
   var bnode = document.createTextNode('\u00A0'); //&nbsp;
   range.insertNode(nnode);
   this.appendChild(bnode);
   range.insertNode(nnode);                                
}
else
   document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>')
```

Where `this` is the actual context which means `document.getElementById('test');`.

Answer (score 1):

I use hundreds of `<td>` elements to input calculated values and found Firefox was adding a `<div></div><br />` on enter which is not cool.  So I used this `onkeyup`:

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.first_td_col', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).empty();

       return false;
    }
    // Do calculations if not enter
});
```

Of course this clears everything from the `<td>`, even the users' input.  But with a message displaying `No enter please.`, it solves unnecessary elements getting in the way of just doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

we can clean html at end like so

```
function cleanHtml(innerHTML: string) {
  return innerHTML.replaceAll('<div><br></div>', '<br>')
}
```

in contentEditable do this

```
const { innerHTML, innerText } = contentEl
          console.log({ innerHTML, innerText, cleanHtml: cleanHtml(innerHTML) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('pre').text($('div')[0].outerHTML)
});

$("#content-edit").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       $(this).find("div").prepend('<br />').contents().unwrap();
      }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jDvau/11/

Comment: It does not let the cursor move forward as you type.

Comment: That is strange, I just tried in Chrome and IE 11 and it works fine. 

[Reference](https://imgur.com/CFqmJRH)

Could you please tell me which browser you are using? Any more details about the behavior would be helpful for solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

Prevent New Div creation in content editable Div on each enter key: Solution That I have find is very simple:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("div"); 
newdiv.innerHTML = "Your content of div goes here";
myEditablediv.appendChild(newdiv);
```

This --- innerHTML content prevent New Div creation in content editable Div on each enter key.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions on the internet and most of them handle keypress same way e.g `execCommand`, `charCode`, `keyCode`, `which`. Unfortunatelly these are deprecated and non-standard features use `key` feature instead of these.

Also do not use `contentEditable="plaintext-only"` try to handle `enter` keypress and insert `br` note to current selection.

Check my solution below it's working without any issue in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge.

```js
function handleEnterPress(e) {
  if (e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(document.createElement('br'));
    selection.collapseToEnd();
  }
  return false;
}
```

```js
function handleEnterPress(e) {
  if (e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(document.createElement('br'));
    selection.collapseToEnd();
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable="true"] {
  background-color: bisque;
  padding: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" onkeypress="handleEnterPress(event)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to prevent this behaviour entirely.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwc6mvcp/)

```
$('<div class="temp-contenteditable-el" contenteditable="true"></div>').appendTo('body').focus().remove();
```