# MaterializeCSS - Change select option font family

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a select element which looks like this:

```html
<div class="input-field container">
  <select>
    <option selected>Roboto</option>
    <option>Kalam</option>
    <option>Karma</option>
    <option>Montserrat</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now, for every one of them, I want to change the font family to what the actual inner html is, to give a preview of the font you're about to select.

But putting styles directly on the option doesn't work for me.

I found a solution targeting all options from css, however, that wouldn't enable me to achieve the wanted behaviour.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried with CSS, but didn't seem to work.

You can use javascript to set the style same as the `option`'s value with the style attribute:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".selectFont option").forEach(function(el){
  el.style.fontFamily = el.value;
})
```

```html
<div class="input-field container">
  <select class="selectFont">
     <option value="monospace" selected>monospace</option>
     <option value="Arial" >Arial</option>
     <option value="sans-serif" >sans-serif</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the style is applied to the element, but it's still not showing :/

Comment: What browser? It works on chrome. But some browsers don't accept styling in options. You'll need to use something else for that.

Comment: I'm on chrome as well.

Comment: yes, I did. Could materialize be the problem in this case?

Comment: Not sude, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but I had the exact same problem - I also wanted to change the font family for text in materialize select options, but after much css manipulation I could not get it to work.

I finally found [this answer by wahmal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176168/materialize-css-remove-styling-from-input-element) - if you add the class 'browser-default' to your select element, it will remove the materialize styling. You can then change the font family of the options. (That said, it won't look like a materialize element any longer if you do this.) Example:

```
  <div>
    <select class="browser-default" id="font-dropdown">
       <option selected style="font-family: 'courier';">courier</option>
       <option style="font-family: 'arial;'">arial</option>
       <option style="font-family: 'Verdana;'">Verdana</option>
    </select>
    <label>Font</label>
  </div>
```

I did not need !important to get it to work. Hope this helps someone.

https://materializecss.com/select.html