# Get text on keydown from contenteditable <p> w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I've got a `<p class="task-name" contenteditable>` and i want to get the text from it when the user presses enter after doing some editing. I've got the event handled...

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'p.task-name', function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
}
```

...but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the value of the entered text. I've tried using `$(this).text` and `event.target`, but i'm getting a lot of `undefined`s. I haven't had trouble with other events this way, so I must be missing something fundamental. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using `keypress` and not `keyup`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid a carriage return being added to the text. With keyup, it was adding it.

Comment: You then have to handle both events. You handle keydown to reject carriage return and you handle keyup to get the value.

Comment: That makes sense. I added a `keydown` function to return false, and changed my original function to use 'keyup'. The carriage return is gone, but I'm still having my original problem. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the edited text.

Comment: Do it on keyup. You handle keyup event and you do this: $("p.task-name").text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.x').on('keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.x {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="x" contenteditable>Dummy text</p>
```

Comment: ha! it was something REALLY stupid. I just didn't have `()` after my .text. But I'm glad I posted, because I still learned some valuable things about keyup/down. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

**You are using keydown** which means the key is down, of course, **and the tag has not yet been updated**. Why? because you could reject that character if you want (you could avoid the user from typing letter in order to have a numeric field, for example). So, **you need to handle keyup event instead** because at that point, the field is already set and you'll be able to get the valud using text property.

If you wanted to reject a character typed by the user, you should use keydown event. And then you grab the value on keyup event.

In order to avoid the DIV created by contenteditable, see this answer: [Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome)

Comment: That could be the case, but I should still be able to get the unedited text right? The main trouble I'm having is that I'm not sure of the syntax to get at the text. I changed my function to use keyup and I'm getting the same results, but with a return added to the text (which i was trying to avoid). I am using preventdefault.

Comment: Then syntax to get the value from a p tag is $("p.task-name").text(). I see that you have marked your p tag as contenteditable so check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome