# How to stop contentEditable="true" inserting <div> instead of <p> when pressing return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    <h1> My headline</h1>
</div>
```

If i am editing the text inside the `<h1>` tag, and press return, it adds a new div under, instead of the normal paragraph tag it usually inserts when entering return

Making it:

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    <h1> My headline edited</h1>
    <div> i tapped return</div>
</div>
```

What i really want is

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    <h1> My headline edited</h1>
    <p> i tapped return</p>
    <p> return again</p>
</div>
```

Whats strange is that usually when you write somewhere and press return it adds a new `<p>`, but just not when editing `<h1>`. Is it possible to fix this with Javascript/Jquery/Html5?

I am using Safari on an iOS-device

Comment: Look at this could be similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome

Comment: I don't want them inside, i want it to add them after, like when you edit another <p>

Comment: Yo should capture ENTER, and attach your own content. What comes to a "normal tag", there's no normal tag (`p` in IE, `div` in most of other browsers, but also possible `br`s etc.).

Comment: "usually when you write somewhere and press return it adds a new `<p>`, but just not when editing `<h1>`"    This is because h1...h6 elements aren't supposed to contain `<p>` tags; according to the HTML spec they can only contain "Phrasing content" which is these tags only: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content

Answer (score 3):

Adding a format blocker inside **onkeyup** with **p** will force the contenteditable (div) to add `<p>` tag on return.

```
editable.onkeyup = (e)=> {
    e = e || window.event
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
}
```

Comment: formatBlock reformats the entire thing. So if you have an H1 there, it'll get converted to a paragraph tag