# Wysiwyg editor puts additional 'div' tags

Tags: html, zend-framework2, tags, wysiwyg

I'm using [ACE theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR) which is modified for zend framework 2. I have a problem with the wysiwyg editor. In their website it doesn't mention about the name or source code etc about wysiwyg...

Whenever I press 'enter' to make a newline, i want it to put 'br' tag but it instead it encloses the text with div tags.

I tried to check the configurations, the init functions of wysiwyg, but couldn't find the way to change it.

Briefly:

This is what i must have

```
text<br>text2
```

This is what it gives

```
text<div>text2</div>
```

Comment: You say `In their website it doesn't mention about the name or source code etc about wysiwyg`, but a quick scan of the page you linked lists `Mindmup Wysiwyg Editor` and a quick search finds their site here -> https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ and the source code here -> https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/  . None of this answers your question, but it's a start ..

Comment: Does shift-enter do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for different browsers,

because google Chrome use div tag on key down event of textarea,
but firefox doesn't do that, it simply add 
 tag.

for more understanding read below link :

[Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome)