# Removing multiline text in contenteditable="true" adds single <br> tag

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have seen many questions related to div tag with contenteditable attribute, but my problem is a bit different.

I don't care whether hitting enter and adding new lines adds `<div>` or `<br>`, but when I select all the text by hitting CTRL + A and then clearing it by pressing DEL or BACKSPACE, it adds additional `<br>`. But when text is only in one line, selecting and clearing it leaves nothing.

How can I avoid the situation when clearing many lines of text adds additional `<br>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome

Answer (score 2):

ContentEditable is managed by the the browser to inject formatting tags as it sees fit; so, if you want plain text, you may be better of with a textarea input.  If that is not a viable option and/or you want all the other formatting, then you could use a javascript or jQuery listener to check innerHTML on each keystroke to see if it contains the rogue br tag and eliminate it.

```
$("div").on("keyup", function () {
  if (this.innerHTML === "<br>") {
    this.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution will work only in Chrome. In Edge, deleting multiple lines of text leaves the last line of this text.

Comment: interesting... it may be an issue with the order in which edge executes passed and native functions.  Not sure if this will work, but try using a function that does not test for keystrokes: like make something that checks for the <br> tag every 500ms.  You might be able to get around the browser's own listener that way.