# UWP Webview Contenteditable div

Tags: windows, uwp, winrt-xaml, microsoft-metro, microsoft-edge

I have a content-editable div in a html page and i have loaded it to UWP WebView. When i edit the content say i enter "Apple" and press enter new line(\n) is getting added but in the edge browser a new line div>br>/div> gets added. Why its behaving differently. I am facing problems in doing text formatting in the webview because of this problem. The problem is when i enter few lines and then when i try add a new list(ordered/unordered) all the lines above are considered as list(as they are considered as same div). Attached screen shots for reference. Please help me with this issue.[image: edge browser behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

Each browser handles enters in editable `<div>` differently so if you want to have control over it, try using the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome).

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. I tried the solution proposed in the link, actually it adds a <br/> tag after i press enter, i want to encapsulate the line content inside a div. For example im typing "Hello" and the press enter the content has to be encapsulated in <div>Hello</div> just like a pragraph.

Comment: I understand, but you might be able to do that as well - get the parent `<div>` and just edit the inner HTML. I cannot confirm 100% as I am not at my PC, but it might be possible in JavaScript. But I am not sure if that will not affect the "cursor" there