# innerText on content editable doubling some line breaks

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to read multi line user input on a content editable div, and I don't get the right number of line breaks when I read the input with `contentEditableDiv.innerText`.

I tried `textContent`, but it doesn't return any line break, while `innerText` returns too many sometimes. `innerHTML` doesn't seem appropriate since I don't want any HTML code, just text.

If my `div` contains:

```
a
b
```

It returns "a↵b" (`97 10 98` in the example)

But if my `<div>` contains:

```
a

b
```

`innerText` returns `a↵↵↵b` (one too many ↵, `97 10 10 10 98` in the example)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  var charCodes = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.innerText.length; ++i) {
    charCodes += input.innerText.charCodeAt(i) + " ";
  }
  result.innerText = charCodes;
});
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" style="border:1px #000 solid"></div>
<button id="button">check</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: If this is a standard `<input>` element, have you tried accessing `input.value` to see if that's accurate?

Comment: It is not a standard input, but a content editable ```<div>```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Inserted code snippet that has the same problem on my side

Comment: @Carlo the result from your code snippet was `97 10 97` for input `a↵a` in my environment, which is Chrome 74.0.3729.169 on Windows 10. Is it different from what you are seeing?

Comment: FWIW, if you run the above example in Firefox `a[empty line]b` returns: `97 10 10 10 98 10`.  
You can find more explanation on `.innerText` and its cross-browser issues [here](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689420/4048698

Answer (score 6):

[The standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html) is a bit vague:

> UAs should offer a way for the user to request an explicit line break at the caret position without breaking the paragraph, e.g. as the default action of a keydown event whose identifier is the "Enter" key and that has a shift modifier set. Line separators are typically found within a poem verse or an address. **To insert a line break, the user agent must insert a br element**.

> If the caret is positioned somewhere **where phrasing content is not allowed** (e.g. in an empty ol element), then the user agent **must not insert the br element directly** at the caret position. In such cases the behavior is UA-dependent, but user agents must not, in response to a request to insert a line separator, generate a DOM that is less conformant than the DOM prior to the request.

To conform this definition, it is safe to wrap the `<br>` element into `<div>`, which Chrome does, but it is UA dependent, so you should not rely on this. The side effect on this behavior and the cause of your problem is that both `div` and `br` elements produces line break in the `innerText` property.

The `innerHTML` of `a↵↵b` looks like this in Chrome:

```html
a
<div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <br>
    <div>
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you paste it (instead of typing char by char) it looks like this

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>b</div>
```

To reduce the line breaks, you need to further process the `innerHTML` and treat
`<div><br></div>` after every input change as a single line-break and then read the `innerText` (with caution on places where phrasing content like `br` is not allowed, but in real life browsers can handle them well).