# How to prevent browser from generating html tags in contenteditable divs

Tags: javascript, html, browser, editor

I am working on an online editor using javascript. For formatting I am using spans and classes(see example below).My problem is after using the editor for some times, the browser adds some unwanted tags to the html content, like `<b>` tags or nested spans. How should I prevent browser from adding tags other than `<br>`?

**Question1** How should I prevent browser from creating `b`, `span`, `font` and other tags when typing?

In the scenario of example below, typing in bold is the desired behavior but using `<b>` instead of a span with `bold` class is causing me trouble!

**Question2** Is there any way to override this behavior? Is there any api to what browser uses to know that it should insert a `<b>` tag?

**Example:**

1- adding style with my editor creates this div and looks like:

[image]
[image]

2- after deleting the word2:

[image]
[image]

3- After retyping *word2*:

[image]
[image]

```
.g1_bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.color_blue{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer is "do not add `<b>` tags" but it's not at all apparent why, where, or how you add them. I'm afraid we cannot just guess why your code does something.

Comment: @VLAZ It is the default behavior of contenteditable divs! I did not coded anything to do that!

Comment: @VLAZ I edited my question. Is it more clear now? I do not think that the question is about my codes!

Comment: I accidentally found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome) which seems very relevant!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you remove all the text from a `<span>` inside a contenteditable div it removes itself from the dom and is not re-added when you type new text. A `<b>` however will be re-added, I would suggest using `<b>` instead of `<span class="bold">` and then replacing this css

```
.bold {
   // styling
}
```

with

```
b {
   // styling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my formatting is based on css classes. So i want to avoid html tags as much as I can.