# Make a newline in a <div contenteditable="true"> make things weird with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on this: http://jsfiddle.net/ms2fV/
As you type in the first div, the second div writes the same thing but with colors.
If you do just one line, it works. But if you add a newline, it starts getting weird, because some div are added...

How can I make it work with multiple lines?
Thanks!

Edit: it works correctly on firefox, but not on chrome nor safari on my mac...

Comment: Im not sure of the problem, it works fine in FF and IE6&7

Comment: You're right, I just made an edit in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your problem, and can be sorted out by changing css like this.

```
#entry {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding:5px;
}
#display {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Nice! But 1) There's still the strange div appearing in the source code and 2) Except for the first line, the colors are not correct.

Comment: Thanks. This extra div problem is solved under this link. but it has written some extra code for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div