# How does execCommand "insertBrOnReturn" work?

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I tried the following code on Chrome:

```
document.execCommand("insertBrOnReturn", false, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVcd5/

Wether I set the last parameter to true or false, the behaviour doesn't change: on return, new `<div>` elements will be added.

Must have missed something... any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`insertBrOnReturn` is a *Mozilla* specific command, *Chrome* doesn't support it. You can test that with:

```
 document.queryCommandSupported('insertBrOnReturn')
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/z6B5N/), it alert `true` in *Firefox*, but `false` in *Chrome*.

If you want to insert `<br>` only, try:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
```

Also, check this: [Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome)

Comment: I wonder why Chrome doesn't insert new P elements by default on return instead of DIV. Would you perhaps know the reason for that?

Comment: Actually, you can make P the paragraph separator by this: document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p'); Also it only works for DIV and P.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.execCommand("insertLineBreak");
```

According to: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp

You can check the specs command at: https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#dfn-the-insertlinebreak-command

Comment: This was a much appropriate solution for my case than `insertHTML` + `<br>`.

Comment: of all the answers, this works the best without having to do any hacks. the only thing odd about it is that it keeps an unused `<br>` at the end but it doesnt seem visible on the page so it isn't really a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this answer but didn't like how in Chrome if your cursor is at the beginning of a paragraph it adds two breaks. Changing the second `<br>` to `\u200C` makes Chrome work perfectly, not so much for Safari.

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<br>\u200C");
```

What is `\u200c?` Not sure. Found it referenced here.

[Dealing with line Breaks on contentEditable DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div)

Comment: U+200C is a zero-width non-joiner, much like the U+200B zero-width space. Note that should the user navigate using the arrow keys, it will have a visible effect, the user will need to press twice to navigate to either side of it.

Comment: When you want to go back by hitting the `Backspace` key, you will need to hit it twice deleting the new `&zwnj;` character and then the `<br>`