# wrap first line of contenteditable in div

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a div with the attribute contentEditable set.

The trouble I am having is that the first line I type does not get wrapped in tags, but the subsequent lines do.

Input

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

Result

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    "abcd"
    <div>efgh</div>
    <div>ijkl</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code?  JSFiddle example of your code?

Comment: I can't understand what you want?

Comment: There is no question in your message. What do you want?

Comment: Looks like different browsers behave differently... http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2009-December/000386.html

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 1):

Try this : get `text` and `children` then make editable div empty and wrap text with div (I have added color:red to just know div added) and children.

```
$(function(){
    $('div[contentEditable="true"]').each(function(){
       var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();// get text
       var $children = $(this).children();// get children

       //add text and children again
       $(this).empty().append('<div style="color:red;">'+text+'</div>').append($children);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngqxm/11/)**

Answer (score -1):

I dont know know what you are asking .but you need result

```
 $("div[contentEditable=true]").text("abcd");
    $("div[contentEditable]").append("<div>efgh</div><div>ijkl</div>");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tcauL/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the OP wants. Did you read the title? This is what he currently gets when he types the given input in a `contenteditable` `<div>`. Line breaks automatically wraps the text in a `<div>`, no need of script, OP is already getting it without it.

Comment: @TilwinJoy k . what he is need  could you tel  me ?

Comment: He needs to wrap the text in first line in a `<div>`, just just the ones after line break...

Comment: looks like different browsers behaves differently though, http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2009-December/000386.html he might not get the same result given in question in all browsers, he probably tested it in chrome..