# adding <br/> to p TAG contenteditable when user press enter key in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add a `<br/>` to `<p contenteditable>` when the user press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in jQuery or javascript?

I tried every solution with no happy ending. A `div` element is always showing.

Currently trying on Chrome browser.

This is the solution for now:

```
$(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
setTimeout(function(){
    $($editedDiv).html($('.ui-selected').html().replace(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/, "<br>$1"));
},100);
```

The problem with this solution is that tha caret location is moving to the start of the sentence when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: The answer was found here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome) Goof luck :)

Comment: The answer was found here: [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div) may be helpful. Of course, with more details, like which browsers you're having issues in (and maybe some code), we could help you pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: The answer was found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome