# jQuery when paste in contenteditable, prevent Chrome text wrapping in <div></div>

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, contenteditable

The problem only happens in Google Chrome, it works fine in Firefox.

Text Simple without format:

```
select its text and paste
Title Example
parrafe

parrafe

parrafe


New Line 
Other Line
```

When paste in contenteditable, Chrome my texts paste return:

```
<div>Title Example
</div><div>parrafe
</div><div>
</div><div>parrafe
</div><div>
</div><div>parrafe
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>New Line 
</div><div>Other Line</div>
```

How prevent, my text wrappin in ?
Chrome should put line breaks

My code Html:

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    Paste Here
</article>
<section>
    <div>
        <span>
            <h1>select its text and paste</h1>
            <h2>Title Example</h2>
            <p>parrafe</p>
            <p>parrafe</p>
            <p>parrafe</p>
            <br/>
            New Line
            <br/>
            Other Line
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

My jQuery code:

```
 $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var text = '';

        if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
            text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        } else if (window.clipboardData) {
            text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        }
        text = text.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');

        if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
            document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
        } else {
            document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
        }

    });

$('[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
     return false;
   }
});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qnu47L5a/

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what result you want? Do you not want the `<div>` tags to be included?  And what is the output when you paste into Firefox?

Comment: In your `keydown` function, try using 'insertText', rather than 'insertHTML'

Comment: @MickelsonMichael I want the pasted text not to insert the <div> </div> tags.

In Firefox return text whitout of divs, Firefox insert <br>, I need that.

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma check out this question for possible solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: Firefox return plain text: "<br>Title Example<br><br>parrafe<br><br>parrafe<br><br>parrafe<br><br>New Line<br>Other Line <br>".

I need the same, without <div></div>