# How to make a content editable div behave like a text area?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have built an [editor](http://brislink.github.io/Abstract/) that converts markdown to html. Right now I have to use [jquery autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) plugin to resize the text area as it grows.

If I use a content-editable div I can bypass it. But the problem with content editable div is that it does not preserve new lines. It inserts a new div every time return key is pressed. This breaks the rendering of markdown to html for my application.

Is there any way I can make a content editable div behave exactly like text area?

Comment: simple answer no. I worked recently with both and got stuck with the same issue. :(

Comment: You could possibly tell the browser to treat any "Enter", while the textarea is in focus, as "Shift+Enter" instead, which would enable it to stay within the same div.

Comment: @Mr_Green well that is too bad really. So is using text area is my only option then?

Comment: can you try html5 `contenteditable` http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: @Duniyadnd That sounds interesting will it work will the content editable div too? I am going to give it a try...

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma Sorry, I misunderstood your explanation. This has a workaround. let me work on it.

Comment: @user108 Yeah content editable div is the problem!

Comment: Have a look at this [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199691/1577396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

After the @Mr_Green comment above, you should have a look at [Make a <br> instead of <div></div> by pressing Enter on a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable/4199691#4199691)

The JS code to make it right is :

```
$(function(){

  $("#editable")

    // make sure br is always the lastChild of contenteditable
    .live("keyup mouseup", function(){
      if (!this.lastChild || this.lastChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "br") {
        this.appendChild(document.createChild("br"));
      }
    })

    // use br instead of div div
    .live("keypress", function(e){
      if (e.which == 13) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
          var selection = window.getSelection(),
              range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
              br = document.createElement("br");
          range.deleteContents();
          range.insertNode(br);
          range.setStartAfter(br);
          range.setEndAfter(br);
          range.collapse(false);
          selection.removeAllRanges();
          selection.addRange(range);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

})
```

;

---

You can intercept the `Enter` key press and replace it with a `<br>` with Javascript :

```
$(function(){
    
      $("#editable").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
             if (document.selection) {
                document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<br/>");
             } else {
                $(this).append("<br/>");
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `document.selection` seems to be work only for IE. Is there any cross-browser solution?

Comment: @Mr_Green We can use Jquery, see the Edit of my answer :)

Comment: Accepted this answer but I guess I will go with the default text area. Making div behave like text area is not worth the trouble for me.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma that would be better. :)

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma Yep, i guess so !

Answer (score 10):

After searching for an answer and not finding anything that worked completely I wrote my own jQuery plugin.

https://github.com/UziTech/jquery.toTextarea.js

I used `white-space: pre-wrap;` and inserted '`\n`' on enter. That way I can use `$("div").text()` to get the text and not worry about removing tags and formatting `<br/>`'s

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/4msdgjox/