# How do I get the text from a div exactly as seen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a prettily styled box for editing some raw text:

[image: Screenshot]

The box is a `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"`. I don't want to use `textarea` because it's so damn annoying to style. Also, the `<div>` has the wonderful property that it automatically scales to contain the text as the user types.

My problem with the div is that I can't seem to get the raw text out of it. When it's edited by the user, the browser inserts `<div>`s and `<br>`s to create line breaks, so when I fetch the text using `innerHTML` I actually get a bunch of HTML rather than the raw text. If I use `innerText` instead, it doesn't preserve any of the line breaks and I get this output:

```
"Foo bar:        PowThis field is:  AlignedWith:           This fieldThree empty lines"
```

### Are there any non-hack, non-workaround solutions provided by the browser to get the text out as it is displayed?

---

One interesting observation is that I can select the text and copy it into a text editor:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This post have some ideas how to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715158/how-to-make-a-content-editable-div-behave-like-a-text-area

Comment: As you can select and copy, have you tried "select all and copy" using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explanation: http://clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent/
of the functions plaintext, innerText and textContent explains that there's a diffrence in the way you get the text back depending on your browser.

**So i'm afraid the easy answer is: No. It depends on what browser you are using to get the indentations etc.**

Comment: Alright, too bad. I could probably make it work OK using a polyfill, but at this point it seems easier to deal with the textarea styling :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4roq1838/1/

`<pre>` tag completely save all formating

**UPD**: innerText is not supported by Firefox

There is a polyfill:
https://github.com/duckinator/innerText-polyfill

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4roq1838/2/