# How to handle backspace and delete in editable div with nested spans and divs?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have an editable **div**, which may contain plain text but also another tags. It may contain **div** and **br** (added by Chrome as the user types text and hits ENTER) and it can also contain some **span** elements with **contenteditable**=false  (because they are updated dynamically from external events.

Like this:

[image]

```html
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
      aaaaaaaa<span style="background-color:#cecece;font-weight: bold;" contenteditable="false">He</span>
      said something.
</div>
```

The two problems are:

**1** - If the user hits Enter between "aaaaaaaa" and the "He", we will have, from a user perspective, two line breaks:

[image]

**2** - Then, with the cursor in the line between, if you then hit delete, then browser also deletes the span (with "He"):

[image]

This is an "electron wrapped site", thus running in Chrome, or Chromium to be exact. I guess I'd would have to interfere when Delete and Backspace are pressed, but I am really struggling to build it.

Anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I've applied the strategy other developers here used: avoid DIV creation when hitting ENTER, instead, use only a BR. Used the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable)